# Can't update npm due to newer version of node

Tags: node.js, npm

So I downgraded my npm version because I've been taking an online course and the teacher uses an older version of npm, that being v5.5.1, and I wanted to be using the same version as him for learning purposes but modules have since been updated and don't work the same with the older npm version so I decided to install the latest version again with:

> npm i npm@latest -g

but when do so I get the warning:

> npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v12.13.1
>
> npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
>
> npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
>
> npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8.

even though Node.js v12.13.1 is the latest stable release and when i check the npm version again it is unchanged.

Is there a way I can update npm to it's latest version without uninstalling and reinstalling node? I tried just installing the latest Node.js version again and the npm version is unchanged.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should probably re-install node since that will install an npm version that does work. However these are warnings and should generally not prevent you from upgrading npm

Comment: it's 2020. Please use containers.

Comment: when i try to update npm the version doesn't change though, so you think reinstalling is the only option? also, that won't adversely affect my current projects the module versions theyre running, right?

Comment: Consider using a node version manager such as [nvm](http://nvm.sh).

Comment: Okay, so I tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling Node.js and the npm version is still at v5.5.1. Is there a way that I can install a new version of npm without using npm to do it?

Comment: What operating system is this on?

Comment: still on windows 7 but upgrading to 10 in the next week. Undoubtedly that should fix it anyway, was just hoping to fix it before then.